Where does Roronoa Zoro gets his superhuman strength from?
So, from the Monster Trio, Luffy ate the Gomu Gomu no Mi Devil Fruit, and Sanji got genetic enhancements. What about Roronoa Zoro?  He can cut metal before having Armament Haki.
Where does Roronoa Zoro gets his superhuman strength from?

In One Piece, humans may have or achieve superhuman strength. Whitebeard (presumably) has it, Oden has it, Garp, Aokiji and Kobi have it by their own admission of doing a special training where they punch warships without Haki or Devil Fruits...

I think since One Piece is an anime originally designed for kids, Oda wanted to use Zoro as an example of "Training makes perfect" as it depicts him training with heavy weights in so many scenes during the anime, so it encourages the younger generation to work towards their goals. I don't really think it's anything more than that.
